# MongoDb Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, makefile

iam newbie to MongoDb..
i have installed mongodb driver 
Are there any "simple" examples for using MongoDb with Ruby On Rails ???
Thank you in advance..
also im getting an error when i try to install gem bson_ext that says : make.exe :unable to locate component. This application has failed to start bcoz msys 1.0.dll was not found..reinstalling application may fix this problem..

Comment: Have you read ruby driver documentation on mongodb site? -> http://api.mongodb.org/ruby/current/file.TUTORIAL.html

Comment: Are you trying to use the mongo driver directly? Have you looked at the MongoMapper or Mongoid ORMs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked at the tutorials [here](http://api.mongodb.org/ruby/current/file.TUTORIAL.html) and [here](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/MongoDB+Data+Modeling+and+Rails)

Answer (score 3):

See the Ruby tutorial [here](http://api.mongodb.org/ruby/current/file.TUTORIAL.html)

There's also:

[Getting started with Rails](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Rails+-+Getting+Started) 

[Getting started with Rails 3](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Rails+3+-+Getting+Started)

[MongoDB Data Modeling and Rails](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/MongoDB+Data+Modeling+and+Rails)

[list of resources relating to Ruby](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Ruby+External+Resources) (screencases, presentations, articles...)

Should be some good stuff there!